# Dependency injection does not work in RestClientBuilderListener

Tags: quarkus, microprofile, quarkus-rest-client

I followed the rest client guide in Quarkus web site. It works fine. But when registering a global provider using the ServiceLoader pattern, as described in the specification, the CDI beans injection did not work, they are all null. I downloaded the example and simply added the following classes:

```
package org.acme.rest.client;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.ext.ResponseExceptionMapper;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ResponseExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    @Override
    public Exception toThrowable (Response response) {
        return new Exception();
    }
}
```

```
package org.acme.rest.client;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.spi.RestClientBuilderListener;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyListener implements RestClientBuilderListener {

    @Inject MyExceptionMapper myExceptionMapper;

    @Override
    public void onNewBuilder (RestClientBuilder builder) {
        builder.register(myExceptionMapper);
    }
}
```

I also added the file META-INF/services/org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.spi.RestClientBuilderListener with the content org.acme.rest.client.MyListener. The MyListener onNewBuilder method is invoked, but the injected provider MyExceptionMapper is null. How to register a global provider in Quarkus client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of `RestClientBuilderListener` are not CDI beans - they are just objects that are created via the normal Java ServiceLoader mechanism when `RestClientBuilder` is being used.

So if you want to obtain CDI beans when `onNewBuilder` is called, you can do something like:

```
CDI.current().select(MyExceptionMapper.class).get()
```

Furthermore, you need to annotate `MyExceptionMapper` with @Provider, not `@ApplicationScoped`.

Comment: I tried that but got No bean found for required type [class org.acme.rest.client.MyExceptionMapper] and qualifiers [ [ ] ] 
Isn't it supposed to just work because of assuming the Default qualifier?

Comment: Not even adding the Default annotation and using CDI.current().select(MyExceptionMapper.class,
            new AnnotationLiteral<Default>() {}).get(); did it work.

Comment: Also, is there a way register the providers globally without using the ServiceLoader mechanism?

Comment: It only worked when adding both the Provider and ApplicationScoped annotations. Also, the ApplicationScoped annotation is unnecessary on MyListener. The need for the Provider annotation makes no sense for me, though. I have many other beans that I want to inject in MyListener, which are not JAX-RS providers, but CDI will only inject them when they are marked as providers. Why? But I guess this is another topic.

Comment: That line of code CDI....   is awesome. THX for it!

Comment: Ahhhhh that lucky day when you find someone asking exactly what you need and there is a single response THAT ACTUALLY WORKS!